# Passing array from Java to VBScript

Tags: excel, vbscript

I have two questions:
**1.** If we can pass an array to VBSCript using java. I am able to pass single variables to VBSCript using  following command

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("wscript openChartsDevice.vbs " + fileName + " " + range);
```

But when I pass a String array, it says type mismatch. I am catching the array passed in

```
Dim arr()
```

any Suggestions?

**Edit 1** Following question has been answered
**2.** I am using following Vbscript to create chart in excel

```
    Dim oExl,excelPath,objWriteSheet,objWriteWorkbook
    Dim oMychartProcs
    Set oExl=CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    Set objWriteWorkbook = oExl.Workbooks.Open("SomeExcelfile.xlsx")
    Set objWriteSheet = objWriteWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
    Set oMychartProcs = objWriteWorkbook.Charts.Add
    oMychartProcs.SetSourceData objWriteSheet.Range(Cells(2,1),Cells(7,6))
    oMychartProcs.ChartType = 4
    oMychartProcs.Name = "ChartName"
    oMychartProcs.Activate
```

I have given the range as A2:F7. when I enter

```
oMychartProcs.SetSourceData objWriteSheet.Range("A2:F7")
```

the chart is created perfectly but when I use the

```
 Range(Cells(2,1),Cells(7,6))
```

whole excel sheet is converted to chart. 
I want to provide the range through parameters so I want above formula to work. I've searched a lot and could not find a definitive way for it. Thank you.

Comment: You should use objWriteSheet.cells(x, y).

Comment: Your first question isn't clear to me. What code are you using to pass the string array? Also shouldn't you have some form of delimitation on your passed in variables when executing the VBS?

Comment: I am creating a string array and trying to pas to a VBScript file and catching parameter in a variable like
Dim var
Var = Wscript.Argument(0)
Same way I want to catch an array. I am asking if it is possible.

Comment: It is possible, but you could run into issues depending on the data size as command line arguments are not really intended for large amounts of data. You would need to convert your array into a delimited string (serialize) and then deserialize the array in your vbscript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not pass array as an object. But you can pass its elements as string parameters to the vbscript function with a space as the delimiter.

```
openChartsDevice.vbs " + fileName + " " + arg[0] + " " + arg[1] + " " + arg[2].....
```

You can a create a method in java to pass an array and return a string

`arg[0] + " " + arg[1] + " " + arg[2].....`

---

**Another Approach:** Create a file with input parameters. Update your VBScript to refer to that input file to get the parameters instead of looking for command line arguments.

Comment: thank you very much... 1st one worked for me.. will try second approach also.

Answer (score -2):

I don't know JScript. But the way to get in VBScript the same thing.

```
For Each thing in Array()
    A = A & thing & " "
Next
```

You are actually asking how to turn an array into a delimited string not a vbscript array.

See this article which your question title implies you are interested in.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2003/09/22/53061.aspx

Comment: Does not answer the question and contains invalid VBScript code.